# copy file from network share to all windows users desktops on all network computers

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, network-shares

Essentially, I would like to do something like this (using command prompt merely for a visual example, will gladly try PowerShell/VBScript/other programming methods)...

```
xcopy "\\thisserver\share\something.txt" "\\computer1\c$\users\dude\Desktop\*.*" /Y
xcopy "\\thisserver\share\something.txt" "\\computer2\c$\users\dudeette\Desktop\*.*" /Y
...
```

In fact, if I could take it a step further to simply the code, I would like to do something like this:

```
xcopy "\\thisserver\share\something.txt" "\\computer1\c$\*\*\Desktop\*.*" /Y
xcopy "\\thisserver\share\something.txt" "\\computer2\c$\*\*\Desktop\*.*" /Y
```

I know this is improperly coded, but essencially I would like to copy a file (.vbs file to be exact) from a easily accessible network location to all the Windows Users' (c:\users) desktop locations on all network computers within our domain.

Any help is greatly appreciated! If manually is the only option, then I guess that's how it is.

Comment: Please show us your code, i.e. what you have tried so far.  We are not a code-writing service.  If you have a specific issue with something you have tries, then indicate that.

Comment: Are you on a domain? If that's the case, a logon script should be easy enough.

Comment: @roryap I know this isn't a code-writing service, I just wanted to know if it was possible. I would write the code myself, just curious if there was an easy reference for doing something like this (whether it would be in VBScript, PowerShell, command prompt, etc.) I know how to to copy the file to each individual desktop for every individual Windows user on every individual networked computer (first sample code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a domain it would be far simpler to use a [Group Policy Preference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772536.aspx) for deploying files to user desktops.

[image: GPP for file deployment]

Press <kbd>F3</kbd> with the cursor in the *Destination File* input box to get a list of available variables.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar! I'll see what I can do with this and let you know!

Comment: How do you depict when group policy propagates the latest version of the file? I created the new file Windows Preference as you suggested and modified the file in the share folder... but it didn't appear on my Desktop.

Comment: @JCBWS Computer GPP are (re-)applied at system startup. User GPP are (re-)applied at logon. You probably want to make this a User GPP (*User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Files*), not a Computer GPP as in the screenshot above.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work upon login (since I'm a member of the security group tied to this GPO)... I'm using the full UNC path to grab my source file (\\thisserver\someshare\something.txt) and I've tried different system defined variables for my destination (%DesktopDir%\something.txt, %CommonDesktopDir%\something.txt, %userprofile%\Desktop\something.txt, etc.); with and without specifying the file name in the destination as well.

Comment: I ended up adding a .cmd file to fire (under User Configuration/Windows Settings/Scripts (Logon/Logoff)) that does the same thing this would have done.
`xcopy "\\server1\users\James Crawford\Windows Scripts\Visual Basic\PDF Search.vbs" %userprofile%\Desktop /Y`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try PowerShell:

- create a text file containing the list of all destination paths, similar to this:

**E:\share\Paths.txt**:

```
\\computer1\c$\users\dude\Desktop
\\computer2\c$\users\dudeette\Desktop
```

.

In **PowerShell**:

```
ForEach ( $destination in Get-Content -Path 'E:\share\Paths.txt' )
{
    mkdir $destination -Force
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath 'E:\share\something.txt' -Destination "$destination\something.txt" -Force
}
```

.

Notes:

```
- I only tested this on the local drives

- if all destination folders exist: comment out "mkdir $destination -Force"
  (place a "#" before the line: "# mkdir $destination -Force")

- if destination paths contain spaces place this line above "mkdir" line
  $destination = $destination.Replace("`"", "`'")

- I didn't test paths with spaces either

- You can rename destination file to "somethingElse.txt" in the "Copy-Item" line:
  ... -Destination "$destination\somethingElse.txt" -Force
```

.

so, version 2:

```
ForEach ( $destination in Get-Content -Path 'E:\Paths.txt' )
{
    $destination = $destination.Replace("`"", "`'")
    # mkdir $destination -Force
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath 'E:\share\something.txt' -Destination "$destination\somethingElse.txt" -Force
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, paul! I might try this as a logon powershell script within the same User Configured GPO I'm working on.